# How to pull content from another database into WordPress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am about to embark on something I have not yet done but I am assuming it is not that complicated to do.

I need to pull content from another MySQL database onto a WordPress page. The other database will be used to track high scores of a game and I need to be able to pull these high scores onto the site.

Could someone please tell me how I would go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wordpress widget that connects with this 'high scores' database, pulls data needed and displays them.

If database is on other server than your wordpress installation it may be not possible to connect to it directly. If so, create a publicly accessible script that pulls the data and outputs them as ie. JSON on the same server where 'high scores' DB. Then create a wordpress widget that reads that data (using PHP or javascript) and displays them.

Comment: Thanks KDZWINEL. How long do you think something like that would take as a complete beginner?

Comment: First option, with direct DB connection, is fairly simple. But if you are new to wordpress and php developement it will take you a few days.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of the JSON option KD please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one, and I don't think there is one. It's a complex task. First, learn how to get data from the database, then how to return it as JSON, then how to write a wordpress widget and finally how to read JSON data from a remote source and display it.